# Integer array definitions: Length

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c, code-review

I'm defining a variable as integer and want to use thati

```
int specLength = 17;
int spec[specLength-1];
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
 TestProgram:34: error: array bound is not an integer constant before  ']' token
 int spec[specLength-1];
```

But when I set it up as

```
int specLength = 17;
int spec[16];
```

it all works fine.

What is the magic here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a constant expression, one that produce always the same value.

```
const int specLength = 17;
int spec[specLength - 1];
```

Otherwise, the compiler won't know how much space reserve for the array.

The problem with C/C++ is that the compiler doesn't really know if a variable is modified somewhere or not (thru pointers, for example). You have to tell the compiler that something is `static`, not changing.

You can also use a #define for the same porpuse:

```
#define SPEC_LENGTH 17
int spec[SPEC_LENGTH]
```

Why both? `const int val=17` means that `val` has a type (`int`). Using `#define` is just a text search-and-replace before compiling. So, SPEC_LENGTH has no type at all. If needed, you have to use a cast, like `(int) SPEC_LENGTH`.